# How to remove all deleted files from repository?

Tags: svn

I have a script in which I add all new files before to commit my working copy to my repository with this line:

```
svn status | grep ^\? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
```

I now want to add a line that delete from repository all deleted files in my working copy. In other terms, I cannot specify them one by one, and I need to detect them with svn status and then automatically remove them. However the line doesn't work.

```
svn status | grep ^\! | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn --force delete
```

As you can see I've replaced

"`?`" with "`!`" and

"`add`" with "`--force delete`"

Could you tell me why it doesn't work ?

ps. I know it is a risky procedure. I've already discussed all about it.
thanks

thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? Why not do it yourself instead of waiting for an answer?

Comment: @viraptor I've just tried, it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is you are trying to remove files which are marked with an exclamation mark which mean something is wrong. This means you have deleted that file by operation system command instead of svn delete which SVN doesn't like......  The problem i don't understand...how did you done the delete of the files which you now want to make permanent by svn rm --force ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm doing this constantly with a php script. I now, it sounds wrong and probably I'm not going to use it. I just want to make the shell script work.

Comment: Did you get an error message?

Comment: I hope I'm not complicating things but, you do know with this you'll delete them from head, right? They are still recoverable by checking out an earlier revision. If you are doing standard code versioning, that's exactly what you want! If you put the wrong stuff in the svn (e.g. confidential stuff in a public repo) then what you need is something else

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I just tried this and it works perfectly.

```
$ svn st | grep '^!' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn delete --force
D         groups.pl
D         textblock.pl
```

Do your files have spaces in their names?

**WAIT A SECOND!!** I see the problem. You have:

```
svn --force delete
```

and not:

```
svn delete --force
```

The `--force` is a parameter of the `delete` command and not the `svn` command.

Comment: I have a question about it. If I delete a file, do I loose all previous versions ? In other words, I cannot revert it anymore right ? So all previous commitments are deleted as well ?

Comment: It still doesn't work... but I'm thinking at this point to use a tool such as rsync to make backups of my files (this comment is out of question, but I realized I cannot use svn like this)

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve a file that was deleted. You need to find the revision of the directory with the file you deleted and use the revision pinning ("@" at the end of the URL). From there, you can copy the missing file to the current revision. You can also do a reverse merge to undo all of your changes. In fact, one of the complaints about svn is you can't completely delete (obliterate) a file in case you committed a file you weren't suppose to (like your password).

Comment: For something that doesn't choke on files within an xCode project (images with the '@' symbol): svn st | grep '^!' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I file svn delete file@

Comment: This doesnt work for files with spaces and special characters. anton_rh's answer does.

Answer (score 44):

I have found another solution, too.

```
svn status | grep '^\!' | sed 's/! *//' | xargs -I% svn rm %
```

I have seen it on http://donunix.blogspot.de/2009/02/svn-remove-all-deleted-files.html

Comment: ! Awesome. Solved my spaces in name issue spendicularly.

Comment: Great Script. Works with spaces too

Answer (score 8):

```
svn status | grep '^!' | sed 's/! *//' | xargs -d '\n' svn delete --force
```

The solution works for filenames with spaces and special characters.

- `svn status` - lists all changes, deleted files are marked as `!`
- `grep '^!'` - extracts lines that begins with `!` (i.e. deleted files)
- `sed 's/! *//'` - removes `!`-char at the beginning and spaces after it
- `xargs -d '\n'` - treats every input line (including spaces and special characters) as separate argument and passes them to `svn delete --force`

Comment: FYI the `-d` option of `xargs` is not supported on OS X - so seems to only work for Linux (or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 2):

what about adding you could simply use

```
svn add --force .
```

or

```
svn --force add .
```

it would do the same: add all unversioned files except ones matching svn:ignore patterns

Answer (score 2):

an approach using a perl oneliner would be:

```
svn st | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^\!\s+(.*)/' | xargs svn rm
```

this should also work with space characters in file names.

edit: improved regexp