# SVN commit does not delete files in remote repo

Tags: svn

When i do

```
svn commit directory_path
```

files that were added or modified are correctly added/modified in the remote repo, but files that were deleted in directory_path are not deleted in remote repo. Is there a way to workaround it?

I tried solutions from
http://www.benjiegillam.com/2009/02/svn-hint-automatically-removing-manually-deleted-files-from-svn/ and
[How to remove all deleted files from repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608798/how-to-remove-all-deleted-files-from-repository/33139931) and neither worked. i keep getting errors like:

```
sed.exe: -e wyrażenie #1, znak 1: nieznane polecenie: `''
```

Comment: Get list of files (if you can't debug sed'-regexp), `svn del --force` by hand

Comment: Your answer solves the issue, which stems from the fact that manually deleted files are not stored for commit. The have to be removed using svn delete (del, remove, rm) command to be included in commit.